# SQL: return IDs whose val=min(exp)

Tags: sql-server

Given a table like

pkg#, time

0, 20

1, 23

2, 34

3, 35

4, 59

I want to know the pkg# who has max/min time difference to its successor pkg (gap between 2 consecutive pkgs)

In this case, pkg-2 has min time difference (1), and pkg-3 has max time difference (14)
What's the sql that can return pkg# for min/max time difference to its next pkg?

Comment: What have you tried already, and how is the output different from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL SERVER 2012 or above, you can try `LEAD` function here to get the next row value to align in your current row:

```
SELECT *, LEAD([time]) OVER(ORDER BY [pkg#]) as nexttime
FROM [your_table]
```

will yield something like this:

```
pkg time    nexttime
0   20  23
1   23  34
2   34  35
3   35  59
4   59  NULL
```

Now compare these two columns values should give you what you want. (Note last row will have nexttime = NULL since there's no more row to get value from, so just filter it out when querying).

Assume new table name is `new_table`, to get max diff:

```
select top 1 *, nexttime-time as diff
from new_table
where nexttime is not null
order by (nexttime-time) desc
```

and to get min diff just `order by nexttime-time`

Answer (score 0):

A slight twist on @xbb 's answer:

```
CREATE TABLE #t ( Pkg INT, Time INT );
INSERT  #t ( Pkg, Time )
VALUES  ( 0, 20 ),
       ( 1, 23 ),
       ( 2, 34 ),
       ( 3, 35 ),
       ( 4, 59 );

SELECT  Pkg
,      Time
,      Time - LAG(Time) OVER ( ORDER BY Pkg ) AS TimeSincePrevious
,      ABS(time - LEAD(Time) OVER ( ORDER BY Pkg )) AS TimeUntilNext
FROM       #t;

DROP TABLE #t;
```

Will yield the result:

```
Pkg  Time  TimeSincePrevious  TimeUntilNext
0    20    NULL               3
1    23    3                  11
2    34    11                 1
3    35    1                  24
4    59    24                 NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at solution below - I decomposed query into three steps:

```
WITH Ordered AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY pkg) rowNum, pkg, [time] FROM Test
),
Diffs AS
(
    SELECT T1.pkg,
           T2.[time]-T1.[time] diff,
           MIN(T2.[time]-T1.[time]) OVER () minimum,
           MAX(T2.[time]-T1.[time]) OVER () maximum
    FROM Ordered T1
    JOIN Ordered T2 ON T1.rowNum = T2.rowNum-1
)
SELECT pkg, diff FROM Diffs
WHERE diff=minimum OR diff=maximum
ORDER by diff
```

1. Number of rows
2. Join with offset 1, calculate diff, MIN and MAX
3. Filter rows not equal to min or max

Query may return more rows if tie occurs. Ties can be simply removed by replacing final SELECT with:

```
...
SELECT MIN(pkg) pkg, diff FROM Diffs
WHERE diff=minimum OR diff=maximum
GROUP BY diff
ORDER by diff
```